# Replace email address using sed

Tags: sed

I have been trying to replace email address in email header, but can't seem to accomplish what I wanted.

```
TO="abc@ghi.com,def@xyz.com"

bash-3.2$ cat mail-pre-tmp.txt
From: xbn@abc.com
To: vxxx@aaa.com,yyy@bbbb.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
Subject: email results

bash-3.2$ `sed "s,To:.*$,To: '"${TO}"',g"` mail-pre-tmp.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown option to `s'
```

Expecting to replace "TO:" to variable set to,  so expected:

```
From: xbn@abc.com
To: abc@ghi.com,def@xyz.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
Subject: email results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's

```
sed "s/To:.*$/To: "${TO}"/g" < mail-pre-tmp.txt
```

with / not ,